# BigQuery table properties affecting query performance

Tags: google-bigquery

This question relates to the performance of querying data in BigQuery.

Any particular table or column settings that would affect query performance, or are all columns in a table in effect treated equally by BigQuery, such that the order of columns or any definitions applying to a column would not impact data fetching in any distinguishable way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All columns are treated equally by BigQuery. The order doesn't matter at all. There aren't any settings that affect performance, but if you import your table in a very large number of small pieces (e.g. more than a few thousand) it can cause some slowdown.